# Test custom hook parameters how many times it is rendered

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library, ts-jest

I want to write Unit Test for the customhook `useImageLoad`. I want to check how many times "onImageLoad" parameter is called.

Initially I was using `onImageLoad` inside useEffect but it was rendering every seconds continously. So I have to use it with `useCallback` hook to run only once. Now its working fine as expected but I want to write a unit test which could get me how many times `onImageLoad` function has been called.

Below is the function:-

useImageLoad.ts

```
import { useEffect, useCallback, useState } from 'react';

export const useImageLoad = (src: string, onImageLoad: () => void = () => {}) => {
    const [isImageLoaded, setImageIsLoaded] = useState(false);

    useCallback(() => {
        onImageLoad();
    }, [onImageLoad]); // render 2 times

    useEffect(() => {
        const newImage = new Image();
        newImage.src = src;
        newImage.onload = () => {
            setImageIsLoaded(true);
        };
        return () => {
            newImage.onload = null;
        };
    }, [src]);

    return isImageLoaded;
};
```

I am trying some way by looking into some tutorial but couldn't help myself how to excetute and run test.

useImageLoad.spec.ts

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { useImageLoad } from './useImageLoad';

type HookWrapperProps = {
    src: string;
    onImageLoad: () => void;
};
// This is just a simple wrapper component since it's awkward to test hooks that rely on
// React lifecycle methods.
const HookWrapper = ({ src, onImageLoad }: HookWrapperProps) => {
    const isImageLoaded = useImageLoad(src, onImageLoad);
    console.log(isImageLoaded, 'isImageLoaded');
    return <div>{isImageLoaded}</div>;
};

describe('UseImageLoad tests', () => {
    it('should return a repository locator', async () => {
        const result = render(<HookWrapper src="test" onImageLoad={() => {}} />);
    });
});
```

Is it possible to achieve same with `renderHook` ?

I am totally noob in unit test. Excuse my code. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.